# Time elapsed for an alternating renewal process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, renewal-processes

Let $\{N_1 (t); t> 0\}$ a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$. These arrivals are registered
by an alternating process: the $n$th arrival of the process $\{N_1 (t); t> 0\}$ turns off the
alternating process during a random time $X_n$ distributed according to $G$, after
which the alternating process reignites. (The $\{X_n\}$ times are i.i.d.)
Suppose the first arrival of the process $\{N1 (t); t> 0\}$ occur at $t = 0$, and define
$L$ as the elapsed time until the alternating process turns on again.
I want to write the renewal equation for $Z(t)=\mathbb{P}(L>t)$. But first, i need an expression for $L$.

Everytime an $N_1$ renewal occurs, the the alternating process (let' say Y(t)) will be of for a random time. So, eventually, this time will be so short that the alternating process will turn back on. So, when:
\begin{align*}
S_{n+1}-S_{n}>X_{n}
\end{align*}
The alternating process will be switched on again, until another renewal for $N_{1}$ occurs. So L must be somthing like:
\begin{align*}
L= (S_{n+1}-S_n-X_n)1_{S_{n+1}-S_n>X_n}
\end{align*}.
So, is there a better expression to get the renewal equation for $Z(t)$ using this L?